# Swing UIManager is not working for JCheckBox html text

Tags: java, swing, uimanager

I am using Java 8 and trying to change default disabled gray color to be little darker. Below is code snippet.

```
    JCheckBox chckbxGraph = new JCheckBox("<HTML>Graph</HTML>");

    JCheckBox chckbxTable = new JCheckBox("Table");
    chckbxGraph.setEnabled(false);
    chckbxTable.setEnabled(false);

    UIManager.put("CheckBox.disabledText", Color.DARK_GRAY);
    chckbxGraph.updateUI();
    chckbxTable.updateUI();
```

Only the checkbox with plain text is changed to dark gray. Is it a bug in Swing?

Comment: Not a bug at all, since you are using html to set the text of the Check box all the customization such as the color is expected to be in the html tag therefore changes to the UI manager will be ignored

Comment: Why then chckbxGraph.setText("<html><font color=red>Graph</font></html>");
  chckbxGraph.setText("<html><span style=\"color:red\">Graph</span></html>"); is not working?